# relocate git's COMMIT_EDITMSG

Tags: git, github, gitlab

By default, Git tries to open `COMMIT_EDITMSG` in the actual repo -- which is sane. But if the repo is on a slow disk (e.g. external USB drive, network fs etc) the editor startup / exit time can suffer.

Short of relocating the repo, or just the `.git` folder associated with the repo (e.g. `.git` file), is there any other way to make COMMIT_EDITMSG go to `/tmp`? I've looked at the hooks but they don't seem to be able to set the location of the file AFAICT.

Comment: No, this is hardcoded in the source: it's always `$GIT_DIR/worktrees/<wt-id>/%s` or `$GIT_DIR/%s` (well, there's one code path that uses `repo->commondir` instead of `worktrees/<wt-id>`, when there's no worktree ID yet, but I'm not sure that can happen for this case).

Comment: Isn't the whole repository going to be slow in that case? Why not just fix it by moving it to a faster disk?

Comment: Yes. But (1) the slowdown is in waiting for the editor, including saving + backup, depending on editor config (2) aborting by saving an empty file is also slow

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to rely on the extended way to use the `git clone` command.

You can tell to git client to relocate the while `.git folder` by:

```sh
git clone --separate-git-dir={{.git folder path}} {{repo URI}}
```

Without the above feature you may try to link the file stored in anothet path like follow:

```sh
mv {{repo-folder}}/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG {{my-custom-path}}/COMMIT_EDITMSG

ln -s {{my-custom-path}}/COMMIT_EDITMSG {{repo-folder}}/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

Comment: Yes, I mentioned using a separate folder in the q. I think you can just move the `.git` folder and replace it with a `.git` file pointing to it at any time. Or use a bare repo etc

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I added to the post an alternative solution. Look at it if suites your needs. Regards.

Comment: I've thought about that, but guessed (correctly, it turns out -- just tested it) that `git` will remove & recreate the file